# Download .zip files from ftp R

Tags: r, ftp, zip, rcurl

I want to download all these files, unzip them and import into R but the download fails after several attempts.

Here is the code (from previous posts) I have tried:

```
library(Rcurl)
url <- "ftp://ftp.nrcan.gc.ca/pub/outgoing/canada_daily_grids/"
protocol <- getURL(url,ftp.use.epsv=TRUE, dirlistonly=TRUE)
filenames <- protocol <- strsplit(protocol, "\r*\n")[[1]]
write.table(filenames, "names.txt", sep="\t")
zips <- sapply(filenames,function(x) substr(x,nchar(x)-2,nchar(x)))== "zip"
downloads <- filenames[zips]
con <-  getCurlHandle(ftp.use.epsv = TRUE)
mapply(function(x,y) writeBin(getBinaryURL(x, curl = con, dirlistonly = FALSE), y), x = downloads, y = paste("C://dat/",downloads, sep = ""))
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to ... port 80: Connection refused
```

[The data is found under this link](ftp://ftp.nrcan.gc.ca/pub/outgoing/canada_daily_grids)

Answer (score 2):

Try using wget instead of curl:

```
wget ftp://ftp.nrcan.gc.ca/pub/outgoing/canada_daily_grids/canada_daily1950.zip
```

This will download one of the files on your computer, and then you can write a shell script to iterate through all the files and unzip them.

Best of luck!